# MySQL backup code Undefined Variable: return

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a MySQL* backup code that i call when i pressed a button, but the problem is that when I'm about to close the file that i use to write the database occurs this following error.

> Notice: Undefined variable: return in C:\

This is my code:

```
     <? php

    backup_tables('localhost', 'root', '123456', 'students');


/* backup the db OR just a table */
function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name,$tables = '*')
{

$link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($name,$link);

//get all of the tables
if($tables == '*')
{
    $tables = array();
    $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $tables[] = $row[0];
    }
}
else
{
    $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
}
$return = ""; 
//cycle through
foreach($tables as $table)
{
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
    $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

    $return.= 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';';
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
    $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
            $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
            for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) 
            {
                $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
                if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
            }
            $return.= ");\n";
        }
    }
    $return.="\n\n\n";
}

//save file
$handle = fopen('db-backup-'.time().'-'.(md5(implode(',',$tables))).'.sql','w+');
fwrite($handle,$return);
fclose($handle);
}

    ?>
```

If any of you guys could help me to understand the problem or help me out with another solution i would appreciate very much.

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: You never actually define the variable `$return` before trying to concatenate with it, `$return. = 'DROP TABLE '.$table...`. Just add `$result = '';`  to the beginning of your function.

Answer (score 1):

Your first reference to `$return` is attempting to append to it. Initialize it first.  Do this, at the top of the function.

```
$return = "";
```

---

The `mysql` interface is deprecated. Use **mysqli** or **PDO** instead.

Are you aware that MySQL provides a utility named `mysqldump` ?

---

As to the design, this is going to attempt to create the entire script in memory, before it writes it to a file. That will work for small number of tables and a small number of rows. But for really big tables, that's going to be expensive in terms of memory. You might want to consider opening the file and then writing pieces of the backup to the file, rather than trying to build the entire thing in memory.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

You've got a serious problem here:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

    for ($j = 0; $j < $num_fields; $j++) {
```

The `for $i` loop doesn't make sense outside of the fetch loop. You want to loop through each row returned, and on each row, you want to loop through the columns on the row.

Comment: And using mysqldump i would solve the memory problem too? i'am already initialized the variable, but know my back.sql is 0KB, so the problem must be in the foreach section, right?

Comment: The MySQL provided `mysqldump` utility produces a file much like the one you appear to be attempting to produce, with a lot more options, and does it much more efficiently than your code will. If this is a learning exercise, then *why on earth* are we using the deprecated mysql interface? I mean, *what the plastic*?

Comment: hmm. i use this code from one of the topics i found here and i thought i would work, but appears is not. So i will search about mysql dump. Thank you.

Comment: You can get code to work, that's not really a problem. But why would you write it using **`mysql_`** functions, rather than using the recommended **`PDO`** or **`mysqli`** interfaces. To be more bulletproof, your code would really need to take into account that an identifier (e.g. a table name) can contain "special" characters, like a space, and your generated `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` statements aren't going to recreate that table. You'd need to account for that.

Comment: It's pretty easy to search for information about `mysqldump`. It's documented in the MySQL Reference Manual, [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to append a string to the variable `$return`, which has not been declared at this point:

```
$return. = 'DROP TABLE '.$table.
```

Simply declare it before the loop starts:

```
$return = "";   

foreach($tables as $table) {
    \\ ...     

    $return. = 'DROP TABLE '.$table.;

    \\ ...     
}
```

Comment: i did what you said and the error is not happening anymore, but the problem is that my back.sql is 0KB now. So i think that jus the $return = "";   is being saved in the file. The problem now would be inside the foreach?

Comment: Could you please add your new code to your original question? Or at least show us where exactly you declared `$return`?

Comment: i did inside the function but out of the foreach, cause is the only place the erro not appear.